# Convert Large number of mysql records to json using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to **convert LARGE NUMBER of MySQL data to JSON** using PHP. **I have 20K and above records** but I am unable to convert MySQL data to JSON. I want to create REST API so need to send(response) data in JSON format.

I have tried this but not getting output:

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT table1.field1, table1,field2, table1.field3, table2.field4 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1");

$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{   
    $result[] = array('Name' => $row["field1"], 'Last Name' => $row['field2'], 'country' => $row["field3"], 'location' => $row["field4"]);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli_* or PDO functions

Comment: i tried brother with mysqli and PDO but still m nt getting output

Comment: you have error in the SQL syntax - `table1,field2` probably should be `table1.field2`

Comment: I'm saying mysql_* are deprecated in newer versions in php

Comment: Do you get any results from the query? You should also set the correct headers if you want to return JSON

Comment: table1.field2 MODIFIED. OUTPUT?

Comment: @Doug . Its showing blank when i am trying to json_encode($result). but when i am retrieving data in array. its success. i want in JSON.

Comment: Can you try getting results and see what happens, I mean get 100 records and convert them in json, I guess your array is getting too large to be converted in json

Comment: @Doug. echo in while do working. i am not getting 864 above records in JSON (LIMIT 0, 864 - in mysql query)

Comment: @Arpita  i am not getting 864 above records in JSON (LIMIT 0, 864 - in mysql. till 864 its showing json records only on condition LIMIT 0, 864

Comment: Instead of json encode, var_dump result. I think you have some bad characters in there breaking jsin_encode.

Comment: yes try looking at 865's elemnt there is something which is breaking json ortry looking at apache logs it must have printed some error log over there (make sure error logging is enabled in php.ini)

Comment: @Doug its showing array. NO bad characters

Comment: During the while, json_encode the array before you add it to $result, then print the id of that row. Eventually it'll break I think before being completed, that will be your problem row.

Comment: @Arpita. I got the error. its because of Bad Character. like á é í ó ñ. How can i replace and UPDATE in database

Comment: Thank u guys.... Its Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asides from the error with your query which I'm assuming is just a typing error in your question because no one labels their columns as field1, field2 etc.

The issue you are facing is more than likely an encoding issue. Try the following which encodes the result as UTF8 and will hopefully result in valid JSON.

```
mysql_set_charset ("UTF8");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT table1.field1, table1field2, table1.field3, table2.field4 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1");

$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    $result[] = array('Name' => $row["field1"], 'Last Name' => $row['field2'], 'country' => $row["field3"], 'location' => $row["field4"]);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: its Done. i had removed bad characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. change it to

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3, table2.field4 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1
```

need `table1.field2` instead of `table1,field2`

Comment: modified. but not getting output

Comment: there is error in your code write `ini_set("display_errors",1);` in first line of your script for a while and this will display errors on page.

Comment: as @Arpita suggest enable error. and then try to solve it.

Comment: @Arpita. No ERRORS.

Answer (score 0):

you have mysql query syntax error. Intead of `table1,field2` use `table1.field2`